# R : combine and save rgl widgets as a single html file

Tags: r, widget, togglebutton, rgl, htmlwidgets

In R, using the **rgl** and **htmlwidgets** libraries, I'm trying to extract an HTML file having a widget *with toggle buttons*.

The following example does what I want in the RStudio Viewer. The HTML export works without the toggle buttons, but fails when the rglwidget includes these buttons.

The first part is based on [these rgl examples](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgl/vignettes/WebGL.html), and the export part on [the htmlwidgets manual](https://rdrr.io/cran/htmlwidgets/).

```
library(rgl)

open3d()

x <- sin(1:100)
y <- cos(1:100)
z <- -100:100/100

# draw a barrel
sids1 <- spheres3d(x, y, z, col = rainbow(1000),radius=0.05)
# draw a pole
sids2 <- spheres3d(0, 0, z, col = rainbow(1000),radius=0.05)

# create widgets with toggle buttons
widgets <- rglwidget() %>%
  toggleWidget(ids = sids1, label = "Toggle Barrel") %>%
  toggleWidget(ids = sids2, label = "Toggle Pole") 

# Works well in RStudio Viewer
if (interactive()) widgets

# HTML export works without the toggle buttons
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(rglwidget(), "x.html")

# HTML export fails with the toggle buttons
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(widgets, "y.html")
```

The second htmlwidgets::saveWidget line fails with

```
Error in system.file(config, package = package) : 
  'package' must be of length 1
```

Indeed, the widgets object is a list of 3 items (3 widgets!). Each item can be saved separately, with for example `htmlwidgets::saveWidget(widgets[[1]], "y1.html")` . This will produce 3 separate html files.

How to combine all these widgets together? According to [this link](https://github.com/ramnathv/htmlwidgets/issues/226), others have similar problems.

If this feature is not implemented, is there another package that would work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `widgets` object is a list of 3 widgets with class `c("shiny.tag.list","list")`, not a widget.  You can save it using the `htmltools::save_html` function.  So instead of

```
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(widgets, "y.html")
```

you want

```
htmltools::save_html(widgets, "y.html")
```

Comment: So simple! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Man, this one is a life saver. I wrote a whole function to save and combine html files files, and then I suddenly found this one. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: can you please take a look at my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65606653/r-saving-multiple-html-widgets-together thanks!